# Display images in tableViewCell from an array of images

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an error message every time when a run this code below to display my image from an array on my cell table view.

The error message:

> Could not cast value of type **'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10b7ae860)** to **'NSArray' (0x10b7ae900)**.

the output of products here is : products   NSTaggedPointerString * "AW"    0xa000000000053552

```js
var product = NSArray!() 
var imageProduct = ["AW":UIImage(named: "MAC.png"),"AC":UIImage(named: "Windows.png")]
         
let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "ABC.png")
let products = product[indexPath.row]

for key in products as! [AnyObject] {
  if let image = self.imageProduct[key as! String] {
    if image == nil {  
      myCell.imageView?.image = initialThumbnail 
    }
    else {
      myCell.imageView?.image = image
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `product[indexPath.row]` is an array?

Comment: yes -->  var product = NSArray!()

Comment: I am not talking about `product`. I am asking if `product[indexPath.row]` is an array?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on it an it show me  products -->NSString -->Anyobject with the value = "AW"

Comment: Isn't it just wrong spelling? I mean an array should be called *product**s***, but instead you called it *product*. And so `for key in products as! [AnyObject]` should probably read `for key in product as! [AnyObject]` since `prduct` is the name of your array. And also, which line is highlighted when the error comes up?

Comment: I changed but still the same problem ... I have this error in this line --> for key in products as! [AnyObject] {

Comment: The exception clearly tells you that the **key** of the `products` dictionary is a string (As is quite common) not an array

Comment: But Products is a string with the value "AW" when a put a break point on it      products NSTaggedPointerString * "AW" 0xa000000000053552

Comment: You don't show where `product` is set but assuming it is something like `imageProduct` shown in your code, then the keys are strings (AW, AC) so force down casting a string to an array will fail, and you have the exception to prove it

Comment: If products is a string then the for loop makes no sense. Perhaps you could update your question showing the output of `print(products)`

Comment: Can you show some code with my example please ! I'm more visual :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96496/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mamoun-mk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `products` is just a string, not an array.  This means you don't need the `for` loop.  Also, you are conditionally unwrapping the image from the `imageProduct` dictionary but then in the next line you check it for nil, which it can't be because you just conditionally unwrapped it.

You want -

```
let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "ABC.png")
let products = product[indexPath.row]

if let image = self.imageProduct[products as! String] {
    if image == nil {  
        myCell.imageView?.image = image
    }
    else {
       myCell.imageView?.image = initialThumbnail 
    }
}
```